# In C++ , variables in the if clause are not initializing

Tags: c++, if-statement

I wanted am a beginner, and wrote this code as part of a project. Depending on the loanCode, I wanted to set different values to variables and print them out. However, The program is just ignoring the initializations in the "if" clauses.
Anyone know what's wrong? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


int main()

{



cout << "This program can be used for new and existing loans!" << endl;


int loanLength;
int paymentPerYear;
double interestRate;
int maxAmount;
int minAmount;

string borrowerName;
cout << "Please enter the borrower's full name: " << endl;
getline (cin,borrowerName);

int loanCode;
cout << "Please enter a BRSL loan code: " << endl;
cin >> loanCode;


if (loanCode == 10)
{
    int loanLength = 30;         // (30-year plan)
    int paymentPerYear = 12;     // (12 payments per year)
    double interestRate = .038;  // (Interest Rate is 3.8%)
    int maxAmount = 425000;      // (Maximum amount is $425000)
    int minAmount = 5000;        // (Minimum amount is 5000)
    cout << "ok 10" << endl;
}

else if (loanCode == 20)
{
    int loanLength = 15;         // (15-year plan)
    int paymentPerYear = 12;     // (12 payments per year)
    double interestRate = .029;  // (Interest Rate is 2.9%)
    int maxAmount = 425000;      // (Maximum amount is $425000)
    int minAmount = 5000;        // (Minimum amount is 5000)
    cout << "ok 20" << endl;
}

else if (loanCode == 30)
{
    int loanLength = 5;          // (5-year plan)
    int paymentPerYear = 12;     // (12 payments per year)
    double interestRate = .026;  // (Interest Rate is 2.6%)
    int maxAmount = 100000;      // (Maximum amount is $100000)
    int minAmount = 5000;        // (Minimum amount is 5000)
    cout << "ok 30" << endl;
}

else if (loanCode == 40)
{
    int loanLength = 2;          // (2-year plan)
    int paymentPerYear = 12;     // (12 payments per year)
    double interestRate = .072;  // (Interest Rate is 7.2%)
    int maxAmount = 25000;       // (Maximum amount is $25000)
    int minAmount = 500;         // (Minimum amount is 500)
    cout << "ok 40" << endl;
}

else
{
    cout << "Loan code is not a valid value." << endl;
    cout << "Program will exit now" << endl;
    return 0;
}


cout << "your loan code is: " << loanCode << endl;
cout << "loanLength: "        << loanLength << endl;
cout << "paymentPerYear: "    << paymentPerYear << endl;
cout << "interestRate: "      << interestRate << endl;
cout << "maxAmout: "          << maxAmount << endl;
cout << "minAmount: "         << minAmount << endl;


return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

This program can be used for new and existing loans!

Please enter the borrower's full name:

Joe Shmoe

Please enter a BRSL loan code:

10

ok 10

your loan code is: 10

loanLength: 0

paymentPerYear: 0

interestRate: 0

maxAmout: 0

minAmount: 0

Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: Look up "variable scope" in your book.

Comment: Turn all of your compiler warnings on.

Comment: You are declaring NEW variables. Not setting the old ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    int loanLength = 2;          // (2-year plan)
    int paymentPerYear = 12;     // (12 payments per year)
    double interestRate = .072;  // (Interest Rate is 7.2%)
    int maxAmount = 25000;       // (Maximum amount is $25000)
    int minAmount = 500;         // (Minimum amount is 500)
    cout << "ok 40" << endl;
}
```

{ ... } opens a new scope. Any new variables declared inside the scope exist only inside that scope.

What you want is to *assign to existing variables* in the scope:

```
{
    loanLength = 2;          // (2-year plan)
    paymentPerYear = 12;     // (12 payments per year)
    interestRate = .072;  // (Interest Rate is 7.2%)
    maxAmount = 25000;       // (Maximum amount is $25000)
    minAmount = 500;         // (Minimum amount is 500)
    cout << "ok 40" << endl;
}
```

... and so on.

Answer (score 1):

"Initialisation" is something you do at the point that you create or "declare" a variable. You're doing it correctly in your program according to the rules of C++, but your program isn't doing quite what you think it's doing so — in a manner of speaking — one might also say that you're doing it incorrectly!

Essentially, all of those variables that you declare and initialise are distinct. **They're different variables.** They have the same names, but it doesn't matter because they exist in different *scopes*.

You will have to declare the variables (initialising them to `0` if you like) *before* the `if` statements (you're already doing this) then, inside, **simply *assign* the new values**.

To assign to an existing variable, you simply write:

```
variableName = value;
```

and *not*

```
type variableName = value;
```

Finally, I strongly, strongly, strongly, strongly, strongly, *strongly* recommend that you **enable compiler warnings**. I don't comprehend why people do not use compiler warnings. Your compiler would have told you about this problem had you enabled compiler warnings, because it's clever enough to spot that this code is almost certainly not what you meant to write.

Answer (score 0):

You already declared your variables outside of the 'if' statements, so instead of this:

```
int loanLength = 30;
```

do this:

```
loanLength = 30;
```